# Find line that is contained in the set

Tags: calculus

I want to find a line that is contained in the set that is defined from the equation $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$.

So we are looking for a line of the form $at+b$, right?

Then $x=a_1 t+b_1, y=a_2t+b_2, z=a_3 t+b_3$.

How can we find some restrictions?

Comment: Suppose that $z=0$. Then, the set is a circumference. How can a curl line contain a straight line?

Comment: Your equation defines a hyperboloid of one sheet. As it turns out, at any point on the surface, there are two distinct lines contained in the surface that pass through the point. Since you only want one example of such a line, take a nice point on the surface, e.g. $(1,0,0)$ and try to find a line.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging in we get
$$ (a_1t+b_1)^2+(a_2t+b_2)^2-(a_3t+b_3)^2=1$$
or
$$(a_1^2+a_2^2-a_3^2)t^2+(2a_1b_1+2a_2b_2-2a_3b_3)t+(b_1^2+b_2^2-b_3^2-1)=0 $$
and this shall hold for all $t$. Thus we need
$$ a_1^2+a_2^2-a_3^2=0$$
$$ 2a_1b_1+2a_2b_2-2a_3b_3=0$$
$$ b_1^2+b_2^2-b_3^2=1$$
To simplify the search we can try to consider the special case $a_1=0$, $b_1=1$. Then the first equation suggests $a_3=\pm a_2$, the third suggests $b_3=\pm b_2$ and then the second holds only if we take opposite signs.
In its simplest case this leads to $x=1$, $z=-y$ or $x=1$, $z=y$.

Comment: From the second equation we get $a_2 b_2- (\pm a_2) (\pm b_2)=0$. Doesn't this always hold if $a_2$ and $b_2$ have the same sign?

Comment: We get $b_3= \pm b_2$ by setting $b_1=0$. $$$$
Also don't we get the following lines?

$$ x=0, y=t+1, z=t+1 \\ x=0, y=-t+1, z=-t-1$$

Comment: @Evinda Note that I set $b_1=1$ not $0$.

Comment: But then from the third equation we do not get $b_3= \pm b_2$ but $b_2^2=b_3^2-1$.

Comment: Or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Extending the remark of @Étienne Bézout, there is a double generation  of the hyperboloid $H_1$of one sheet by the following straight lines:

$(D_{\lambda})\begin{vmatrix}(x-z)=\lambda(1-y) \\ (x+z)=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}(1+y) \end{vmatrix}
\Rightarrow (x-z)(x+z)=(1-y)(1+y) \Rightarrow x^2+y^2-z^2=1  $

$(D_{\mu})\begin{vmatrix}(x+z)=\mu(1-y) \\ (x-z)=\dfrac{1}{\mu}(1+y) \end{vmatrix}
\Rightarrow (x-z)(x+z)=(1-y)(1+y) \Rightarrow x^2+y^2-z^2=1.$

One knows that implication corresponds to set inclusion ; thus each straight line $(D_{\lambda})$ is included in $H_1$. The same for straight lines $(D_{\mu}).$

In fact, it can be easily proven that each point $(x,y,z)$ of $H_1$ belongs exactly to one straight line of type $(D_{\lambda})$ and one straight line of type $(D_{\mu}).$

[image: 100 straight lines of type $(D_{\lambda})$ and 10 of type $(D_{\mu})$]

Figure: 100 straight lines of type $(D_{\lambda})$ and 10 of type $(D_{\mu}).$

Answer (score 0):

The line 
$$l: \begin{cases} x=1 \\ y=z \end{cases}$$
satisfies the equation of your curve. Other similar ones work: invert $x$ and $y$, or use $y=-z$.

Answer (score 0):

this is similar to hagen von eitzens idea. take a point $(\cos s, \sin s, 0), 0 \le s < 2\pi, $ on the $xy$-plane. now consider the lines $$x = \cos s - t\sin s, y = \sin s + t\cos s, z = t, -\infty < t < \infty\tag1 $$ parametrized by $s, t.$

we can verify that 
$$\begin{align}x^2 + y^2 - z^2 &=( \cos s - t\sin s)^2+(\sin s + t\cos s)^2 -t^2\\&= \cos^2 s + \sin^2 s+t^2(\sin^2 s + \cos^2 s )-t^2\\&=1\end{align}$$
as required.

Comment: Can you take a look at the results that I found at the comments of hagen von eitzens post? They don't satisfy the given equation ? Why?